# Getting angle between two GPS coordinates

Tags: math, gps

We have static point at **lat1,lon1** and moving point with **lat2,lon2** and direction **D**. Direction is an integer that comes with GPS coordinates.

Two points distance is a few kilometers, so we can suppose that earth is flat.

How can we check if second point moving in direction of first point or not? And if not how to calculate "right" direction for second point.

P.S. I will be also grateful for any good documentation about how direction from PGS coordinate pack works.

Comment: How is direction D defined? Is it an azimuth angle or something else?

Comment: @Hun I don't know. it's integer from pack of data from android (with lat, lon and timestamp).

Comment: I would first make two plots. We can forget about lat1, lon1 since it is fixed. So make a plot of x=lat2, y=lon2 (with occasional time marks on the plot). And make another plot of x=time, y=D. Seeing that plot can give some insight.